# serialize does not send some items in jquery

Tags: jquery, serialization

i want to send **input,dropdown and textarea** in **custom div** 
i tried this with :

```
$('#rs-'+row).find('select, textarea, input').serialize();
```

but some item not sended!!
what should I do?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can only guess based on snippet shown. Make sure each element has a `name` also

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = $([parent element]).find('select, textarea, input').serialize();
console.log(data);
```

see if the output is correct